# Converting RTMP to RTSP in NGINX

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, server, rtsp, rtmp

I have a question, if I use nginx for RTMP stream, can this function to stream video with RTSP?

What are the differences between RTSP and RTMP? Can I use my RTMP server to stream with the RTSP protocol?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: so is there a way to do that (from rtmp to rtsp)?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I want to clarify some concepts for future visitors.

> I have a question, if I use `nginx` for RTMP stream, can this function
> to stream video with RTSP?

The answer is **NO**. Your `nginx` server will stream using the RTMP protocol. What you can do is: Receive a stream from a RTSP protocol and convert it into a RTMP protocol using `ffmpeg`.

> What are the differences between RTSP and RTMP? Can I use my RTMP
> server to stream with the RTSP protocol?

The main difference is that they are different protocols. It is like talking about UDP and TCP. U can't send data using UDP and receive it using TCP. What you can do is send data using UDP receive it using UDP and the re-send it using TCP. So that is what we gonna do here.

Answer (score -1):

Using nginx-rtmp, you still can add on-the-fly encoding of your RTMP stream to RTSP using ffmpeg.
Example of the config:

```
rtmp {
   access_log /var/log/nginx/rtmp_access.log;
   server {
       listen 1935;
       ping 30s;
       notify_method get;
       application camera1 {
           live on;
           exec_pull ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.10.11/axis-media/media.amp -threads 2 -f flv -r 25 -s 1280x720 -an rtmp://localhost:1935/cam1/stream 2>>/var/log/nginx/ffmpeg.log;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are converting from RTSP to RTMP in that example, hence your answer is misleading.

Comment: Is there a way to convert RTMP to RTSP/RTP?

Comment: This is misleading. You are pulling from rtsp source and converting it to rtmp.

Answer (score -9):

RTMP - proprietary protocol from Adobe, RTSP is open standard from IETF.
They are not compatible with each other.

Comment: RTMP was open sourced a long time ago.